# TypeError: game_1.flip is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop, firefox

I am trying to make an OOP version of a simple concentration game. Everything looks good, i.e. the game boards and the cards show up for each instance of the game, but the cards won't flip.

I am trying to debug using Firefox Web Developer and this is error message I am receiving:

> TypeError: game_1.flip is not a function.

I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with the flip function. I have read a couple of TypeError questions and responses but none seem to apply to my problem.

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>"More Concentration"</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />  
    <style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:green;}
        p {color: white}
        img {border:1px solid black}    
        #theGame {width: 400px; height: 390px; border: 1px solid white; padding:15px; text-align: center;  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
        #wrapper {text-align: center;}
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function Card() {
this.value = ""; 
this.suit = ""; 
this.name = ""; 
this.image = ""; //add a spot to store a path to the card image.
}
function Game(gameId) {
this.gameId = gameId;   
var firstCard = 'unused'; // A place to remember the first pick...
var touchedCard = 'unused'; // ... and the last touched card
var waiting = false; // This variable will control WHEN we can flip cards.
this.Deck = new Array(52);

this.shuffle = function() {
    var r;
    var someCard = new Card();

    for (i=51;i >= 0;i--){
        r = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
        someCard = this.Deck[i]; this.Deck[i] = this.Deck[r]; this.Deck[r] = someCard;
    }
};

this.initDeck = function() {    
var Names = new Array("2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","jack","queen","king","ace");
var suitNames = new Array("spades","diamonds","hearts","clubs");
    for (var i=0;i<13;i++){
        for (var j=0;j< 4;j++){     

        this.Deck[i + (j * 13)] = new Card();
        this.Deck[i + (j * 13)].suit = suitNames[j];
        this.Deck[i + (j * 13)].value = i;
        this.Deck[i + (j * 13)].name = Names[i];

        //This line builds the path to the card image based on available info.
        this.Deck[i + (j * 13)].image = 'images/' + suitNames[j] + '_' +  Names[i] + '.png';

        }
    }

};

this.flip = function(passedCard){
//This function is the core of the interactivity

    if (waiting == false){ 
    //check to see if we're "waiting" for any flips to finish

         touchedCard = passedCard;

         document.images[touchedCard].src = this.Deck[touchedCard].image;

        if (firstCard  == 'unused'){ 
                   //If this is the first cards selected...

            firstCard = touchedCard; // ... remember it for later

        }else{ //If this is the second card selected ...

            waiting = true; //... disallow further flips and ...

            if (this.Deck[touchedCard].value ==  this.Deck[firstCard].value){ // ... compare it to the first.

                //If they match, do this.//


            setTimeout(this.gameId + ".retireSelection("+ this.firstCard + '_' + this.gameId + ","+touchedCard+")",2000);

            } else { 


                setTimeout(this.gameId + ".resetSelection("+   this.firstCard + '_' + this.gameId + ","+touchedCard+")",2000);
                }

                 firstCard  = 'unused';

        }
    }
};


this.resetSelection = function(carda,cardb){
      //Turn the cards facedown after NOT matching
    document.images[carda].src = 'images/card_back.png'; 
    document.images[cardb].src = 'images/card_back.png';
    waiting = false; // re-allow more flips
};

this.retireSelection = function(carda, cardb){
    //Indicate the cards are matched using the "X' card.
    document.images[carda].src = 'images/blank.png';
    document.images[cardb].src = 'images/blank.png';
    //Deactivate the handler so they can't be flipped again after a match.
    document.images[carda].onclick = '';
    document.images[cardb].onclick = '';
    waiting = false; // re-allow more flips

 };

 this.plop_cards = function(){
     //Writes HTML to put cards on the page     
     this.shuffle();
    //document.writeln("<p>" +this.gameId + "</p>");
    document.write('<div id="theGame">');
     for(var i=0;i<52;i++){     
    document.writeln("<img src = 'images/card_back.png' id =" + this.gameId +  ' Card_' + i + " onclick='" + this.gameId + ".flip("+i+")'>");

    }
    document.write('</div>');
 }; 
 }  
     // ]]>
</script>
  </head>
  <body>      
  <div id="pageTitle">
<h1>&quot;More Concentration&quot; <br /> By Dawn Lassen</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper" class="center">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[


    var game_1 = new Game('game_1');
    var game_2 = new Game('game_2');
    var game_3 = new Game('game_3');
    var game_4 = new Game('game_4');
    var game_5 = new Game('game_5');

    game_1.initDeck();
    game_2.initDeck();
    game_3.initDeck();
    game_4.initDeck();
    game_5.initDeck();

    game_1.plop_cards();
    game_2.plop_cards();
    game_3.plop_cards();
    game_4.plop_cards();
    game_5.plop_cards();

    // ]]>
</script>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Any help, guidance, suggestions are appreciated. As you can probably tell, I am new on this forum and to JavaScript.

Comment: I feel like you are missing some code out here, if you could include an example of where you are making an instance of the Game that would help and I can write a full answer. I think the problem you have is where you assign the `onclick` attribute of the img, as you use `this.gameId` but unless `this.gameId` actually evaluates to a variable which refers to an instance of your `Game` class, it won't be able to call that method, if you understand where I'm coming from? Very nice code by the way, commented well and is easy to follow.

Comment: Fred thank you for responding. I will edit the code and include the body of the page where I am creating instances of the game.

Comment: Also, if I understand you correctly, this.gameId does seem to evaluate to each instance of the Game object.

Comment: See this fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/h6EPX/1/ ) for a quick demonstration of how avoiding `document.write` will allow `flip` to be called (it destroys the formatting for now, but it's just to show the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating invalid (X)HTML when you write the image. See this line of your code:

```
document.writeln("<img src = 'images/card_back.png' id =" + this.gameId + ' Card_' + i + " onclick='" + this.gameId + ".flip("+i+")'>");
```

The `id` attribute has no quotes and therefore the output will be jibberish, because it will contain something like `<img ... id=game_1 Card_1 onclick=...>`. For one this is simply wrong, because all cards of one game will have the same id (which is invalid in HTML as well, and also not what you want), and especially in the case of XHTML unquoted attributes are forbidden.

The easy fix is to quote it properly

```
document.writeln("<img src = 'images/card_back.png' id ='" + this.gameId + ' Card_' + i + "' onclick='" + this.gameId + ".flip("+i+")'>");
```

**However**, it is a bad idea to attempt writing to the DOM stream directly. It would be much better if you avoided methods like `document.write` altogether as it is generally recommended not to use them, in favor of DOM methods.

For example, you can do something like this:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'images/card_back.png';
img.id = this.gameId + ' Card_' + i;
img.onclick = (function(_this, i) {
    return function() {
        _this.flip(i);
    };
})(this, i);
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

You can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h6EPX/1/) fiddle that it will allow `flip` to be called. The fiddle destroys the formatting of your page for now, it's just a quick demonstration. I'd also advice against using `id` attributes with spaces, by the way.

Out of curiosity: is there any specific reason you are using XHTML? You could just as well use HTML (i.e. HTML5) and then also get rid of the CDATA block comment around your script. While XHTML is more strict, which generally is not too bad of a thing, HTML5 is far more spread, so there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: Ingo thank you!! That fixed the problem with the flip function. I should always remember to validate my code especially when using XHTML Strict. I am using XHTML because that is what I was taught in college. I am a recent graduate. We always had to use XHTML, so I sometimes forget that there is any other way.